# HP laptop power problem, won't start

Tags: power

I shut the laptop down last night properly. Now while trying to turn it on with AC Adaptor it is not responding in any means. The only lit led is charging one, indicating that it has got the adaptor in and is recieving power. When I try to turn it on only with the battery then the charging led starts blinking for 7 times and then again dies, nothing else happen. No power up and even processor fan remains stationary. I just cant start it up.

Comment: Which HP laptop do you have?

Comment: Its compaq nc6400

Comment: Nobody's here ?